# Mysql docker on centos not working

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, percona

I use centos as server and I use docker-compose like:

```
  mysql:
    build: ./DockerFiles/Mysql
    ports:
    - ${LOCAL_PHP_IP}:${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    privileged: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
    - /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

when I run

> docker-compose up -d

the container will stop and when i check the log, I get following error :

```sh
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
command was: "mysqld --verbose --help"
```

my Mysql Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM percona

MAINTAINER Alireza Rahmani Khalili "alirezarahmani@live.com"

ENV TERM xterm

RUN mkdir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
RUN chmod 755 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

please consider only on centos server it return this error, I tried it on local, it works properly. Also, i use gitlab-runner to run this.